# c++, why use const std::string & parameterName?

Tags: c++

While viewing some code I came across a method with the following parameter

```
methodName(const std::string & parameterName)
```

I know const is used for a value that can't change in the method, and & is a value of a reference.

Why and when should you use this and not just a const string?

Comment: Note: the  flavour 'void f(const T)` without reference is just an implementation detail (preventing modifications on a copied argument)

Comment: What book do you read that does not cover such a basic thing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- `const` is an assurance that the function will not change the argument.
- `&` is a reference; that means that the string passed to `methodName` is *passed by reference*. This has the advantage that it is **not copied** and therefore **improves performance**.

In combination, it's a common pattern for passing big objects efficiently. A simple `const std::string` would copy the whole string, which, for long strings, would be pretty inefficient.

---

Since C++11, you can also pass objects efficiently by [moving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-are-move-semantics) them.

Answer (score 1):

> I know `const` is used for a value that can't change

`const` is used for anything that can't change - a value, a pointer, or a reference. It is a good idea to use `const` in situations when something is not supposed to change, even if you pass it by value.

> Why and when should you use this and not just a `const string`?

`const string&` is more economical, because it lets you avoid copying the content of the string. You should use it when the `string` that you are passing to the function is guaranteed to remain in place for the duration of the function. This is always the case when you call a function directly.

In contrast, `const string` should be used when there is a possibility that the string could be deleted while the function is still running.

For example, this could happen when you call a function on a different thread, and then delete the parameter that you passed to it, or let the parameter go out of scope. Trying to pass the parameter by `const` reference would result in undefined behavior, while passing it by `const` value would make a private copy, thus preventing UB.

Answer (score 0):

Notwithstanding all answers here, sometimes it is actually preferable to pass strings by value, and that would be specifically for performance gains. A most common example would be an implementation of `operator+` for strings.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `const std::string` instead of `const string`, because you are using the C++ String Class which is not accessible to your program globally.

This is because the C++ String Class is defined under the namespace `std` (namespace is a set of classes), and to use the C++ String Class you will need to access that from that namespace. Also, you would need to use scope resolution operator (::).

syntax:

```
<namespace_name>::<class_name>
```

Hence you need to use `std::string`.